# Бэкап на сетевой диск

Tags: sql-server, резервное-копирование

Настраиваю бекап БД на сетевой диск.
Бекап осуществляется через агент, агент использует не доменную учетку, а свою NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT.

В sql server configuration manager хочу изменить имя входа на учетку с правами админа, но по умолчанию стоит учетка NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT с паролем, а вот что эт за пароль я понятия не имею. И при установке не помню, чтобы задавал.

Почему эта учетка запаролена?
И если я поменяю имя входа на админскую учетку, перестанет ли вылезать ошибка доступа (5) при бекапе, которая возникает, как я думаю, из-за отсутсвия прав у NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT на сетевом диске?

Comment: есть предположение, что пароля никакого нет, а звездочки просто стоят для виду? Переключил запуск службы на админскую учетку, сетевой диск через мастер бекапов видит, но при самом запуске вылетает ошибка (5) отказано в доступе. Какие права назначить? Если sysadmin, то тогда перестает видеть сетевые диски

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ЕМНИП, для SQL Server'а важна учетка, из-под которой работает служба самого сервера, а не агента.

Если вы измените учетную запись для запуска SQL Server'а на учетную запись, имеющую права доступа к шаре, проблемы с доступом должны уйти, только обратите внимание на то, что учетная запись должна обладать достаточными правами в системе, в которой работает SQL Server.

Для простоты можно дать этой учетной записи права администратора, хотя с точки зрения информационной безопасности это не совсем правильное решение.

Comment: а восстанавливать бд тоже из под этой учетки придется?

Comment: При восстановлении БД доступ будет проверяться для той же самой учетки - учетки, из-под которой работает SQL Server.